# Bowing when davening outside

Tags: tefilla, avodah-zarah, bowing-kneeling, aleinu-leshabeiach

If one is [davening](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28283/is-it-permitted-for-a-minyan-to-daven-outdoors) outside, and one says aleinu* and wishes to [bow](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31290/bowing-during-aleinu), should one change how he bows?

I have seen (h/t Harel13) it [written](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/general/pdfView.aspx?src=/midrash/pdf/pdf110/birkatahama3.pdf) that, when one says Birchat Hachama, one should bow to the side.

[image: aleinu bowing to the side]

I recall hearing as a boy (2 Birchat Hachama cycles ago) that this was to avoid the appearance of bowing to the sun, which others might misunderstand as worshiping OF the sun.

-- another source which quotes the Chida among others https://www.hidabroot.org/article/238621

Does this same concern apply whenever one davens outside and says aleinu?

*might this also apply to any other bowing done while davening silently, as an outsider would not know what is being said and might [misconstrue**](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53252/1362) the behavior for sun-worship?

**if the fear is others misunderstanding the bowing as worshiping the celestial object, would one change the bowing during Kiddush Levana for the same reason? (h/t Sam)

Comment: You have same issue every month by kiddush levana

Comment: @sam I was just coming here to add that to the question, especially in the light of the linked question.

Comment: I don't know much on the topic, but I was once told the we say Aleinu at kiddush levana to demonstrate the exact opposite - that we are NOT praying to the moon.